# Building a simple windows service in C# - not installing, why?

Tags: c#, windows-services

It's been a long time since I've built a Windows service.  I followed a guide for building a new service, but am having trouble installing it.  I created a new service based on "Windows Service" Visual Studio project template.

No other changes.

#### Service1.cs class:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    private ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Service1));
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        log.Info("OnStart");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        log.Info("OnStop");
    }
}
```

I added `ProjectInstaller.cs` as instructed.

That is it. Built. No problem.

Now I ran:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise>installutil.exe c:\Users\myusername\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe
```

But I don't see my service in the Services window.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to install it by executing command in command prompt

Comment: I would recommend using [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) to develop the service. I have found it much, much easier than using the default template. You develop the service in a console app, then test and deploy as a service.

Comment: I am using Topshelf on other projects, for this one the code is already written, I just need to make some changes

Comment: Oh, damn, I had to run the console in Administrator mode :) Now it works

Comment: If you have solved the problem, maybe post your solution as an answer? That will help future visitors, and highlight that your question has an answer.

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt - "I didn't run the console as Administrator" (which implies "I didn't read the output from `InstallUtil`") I think would fall into the category of unlikely to be of assistance to future visitors and should be closed.